# What do the icons on the glyphs mean?

Tags: warframe

In the new update (Silver Grove), a new icon system was added, which turned all profile related icons into "glyphs"

On the page in which these glyphs are listed there are some icons at the top right, some look like a trophy - what do these mean?

Comment: From the patch notes: GLYPHS
Now you can place your mark around your environment using Glyphs! Show your foes you are close by or simply show off your favorite Warframe. 

How To Use:

A Glyph Prism awaits you in your Gear wheel!
Access your Glyphs in the new ‘GLYPHS’ category under PROFILE in the menu, and select which Glyph you would like to use! GLYPH is now the catch-all word for Profile Pictures, so you'll see your Glyph selection determine that and your Forum Profile!

Comment: @MacedonZero That does not help with this question, it is regarding the symbols at the top right of certain glyphs, such as a trophy or a blue symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purple trophy icon means the glyph is "premium".

There are two types of glyphs, normal and premium. All the light and dark versions of normal Warframes, including their non-tennogen alt-helmets, are normal glyphs. Everything else carries the trophy icon.